# How to make a dynamic react progress bar

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a dynamic process bar for a countdown from a start date to the endDate. (e.g) from 20-11-2020 to 30-12-2020 using react hooks.

Comment: Can we see what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please share details about what you want to achieve, what you have tried and what you ran into so far.

Comment: This [blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-countdown-timer-react-hooks) can solve your problem.